# add multiple scrollbar in a same page using perfect-scrollbar plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I have used perfect-scrollbar js plugin. scrollbar works fine. But when I add this scrollbar again for a another content(**same page**), it doesn't work for second `div`. How do I add multiple scrollbar in a same page using this plugin?

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      "use strict";
      $('#Default').perfectScrollbar();
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#Default.contentHolder { position:relative; margin:0px auto; margin-top: 20px; padding:0px; width: 285px; height: 450px; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Default" class="contentHolder">
/*content goes here. scrollbar works fine here */
</div>

 <div id="Default" class="contentHolder">
    /*another content goes here. scrollbar does not work here*/
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have same ID on multiple elements.
2. Use Classes for assigning the plugin.
   For example:

   ```
   $('.contentHolder').perfectScrollbar();
   ```

or you can also use `.each` loop if it doesn't work. For example:

```
$('.contentHolder').each(function(){
    $(this).perfectScrollbar();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

For latest version use this

```
$('.dialogInner').each(function(){ const ps = new PerfectScrollbar($(this)[0]); });
```

https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar/issues/246#issuecomment-356918832

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contentHolder').each((index, element) => {
    new PerfectScrollbar(element);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**